# Getting GL Impact of ITM/RECT for Serialized Inventory

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to get the debit/credit values from the GL impact of an ITM or RECT. We are using Serialized Inventory in this scenario which is why these records have a GL Impact. I have attached a screenshot below. I want to be able to loop and get this information. I need to get it through Suitescript, currently in a scheduled script and have loaded the record and am looping through the lines. I just don't know if these values are part of the line or somehow accessible in a different way. Please advise.

[image: GL Impact]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward to get this from an item receipt or fulfillment.  Here's a simplified version of the function that I use to get the GL impact.  I'm not sure if it's going to match the GL Impact screen 100% of the time with all transaction types but it works for Item Receipts and Item Fulfillments.

```
function getGlImpact(recordType, recordId) {
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord(recordType, null, [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', recordId)
    ], [
        new nlobjSearchColumn('number', 'account'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('debitamount'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('creditamount')
    ]);

    return (results || []).map(function(line) {
        return {
            account: line.getValue('number', 'account'),
            debit: line.getValue('debitamount'),
            credit: line.getValue('creditamount')
        };
    });
}

var impact = getGlImpact('itemreceipt', 1837546);
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question/answer, but I haven't seen quite this pattern for searching and translating results. I like it.

Comment: I'd much rather pass around plain object arrays than `nlobjSearchResult[]`.  Makes code further down the line easier to read.

Comment: Totally agree; I always do something similar, but it's usually in a separate function; this pattern helps condense that a bit.

Comment: @MikeRobbins - First, thank you. I do have a few questions. So the fields are only accessible by running a search? I can do that, just trying to avoid the script usage if there is a more direct way. 
Also, just so I understand your code, is var impact an associative array basically then? So to access say debit would be impact[debit] ? Also, how does it display for multiple lines? How do I know which result line ties to which ITM/RECT line?

Comment: I can't answer if this is the *only* way but it appears that `debitamount` and `creditamount` are not available if you load the record and inspect the line items directly.  It appears that those fields are only available as search columns.  `var impact` is an array of objects.  Each object represents a line on the transaction.  You can add additional fields to the search as you need so you know which line is represented. Consult the Records Browser to see what fields are available:  https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_2/script/record/itemreceipt.html

Comment: This did work as expected. I used the Line ID (field id is "line") from both the ITM and the search results to join together. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeRobbins - this suddenly stopped working. I am logging the line.getValue() calls before the return and debitamount and creditamount return blanks. I have the account field and I added line id and both return results. But I am not getting any value back from line.getValue('debitamount') or line.getValue('creditamount'). I also tried creating the search in the UI and loading it and it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is if you're filtering mainline == 'T' then the search will not return any debit or credit values.